# Import Magento Orders CSV with PayPal transactions?

Tags: php, magento, csv, paypal, import

I am using [Bulk Import+Export Orders](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-import-export-orders-to-csv.html) to CSV extension to import my old orders into Magento and it works pretty good for it.

When I tried to put payment method as "paypal_express" it still was importing the orders of type "checkmo".

Upon looking into the source code file on line 182:

```
/app/code/community/Raveinfosys/Exporter/Model/Createorder.php
```

I found this:

```
$orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
          ->setStoreId($this->store_id)
          ->setCustomerPaymentId(0)
          ->setMethod('checkmo')
          ->setPoNumber(' - ');
         $order->setPayment($orderPayment);
```

Which means, the value for payment method was static. So I went ahead and changed it to this:

```
$orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
          ->setStoreId($this->store_id)
          ->setCustomerPaymentId(0)
          ->setMethod($sales_order_arr['payment']['method'])
          ->setPoNumber(' - ');
         $order->setPayment($orderPayment);
```

Now the problem is, it tries to verify the payment through PayPal servers and gives the PayPal verification error.

What I want is to create an order with method PayPal and without verifying it through PayPal, because I have many orders to import.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!